# table references a table which in turn references another table

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm using gorm, and I have this structure where the `User` table contains a foreign key referencing `Address`, which then references `Country`.

```golang
   type User struct {
      ID              int       `gorm:"column:id; primaryKey; autoIncrement" json:"id"`
      Address         Address
      AddressID       int  `gorm:"column:address_id;foreignKey:AddressID;references:ID" json:"address"`
   }

   type Address struct {
      ID          int `gorm:"column:ID;primaryKey;autoIncrement;" json:"id"`
      CountryCode int `gorm:"column:country_code; foreignKey:CountryCode; references:Code" json:"country_code"`
      Country     Country
   }

   type Country struct {
      Code          int    `gorm:"column:code; primaryKey; autoIncrement" json:"code"`
      Name          string `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
      ContinentName string `gorm:"column:continent_name" json:"continentName"`
   }
```

**relationship explained in the photo:**

[image]

Now when I return a user using:

```js
  db.Model(&user).Where().First()  // or Find()
```

I get the Address, and Country Empty, like this:

```json
   {
    ID: 1,
    AddressID: 2,
    Address: {
          // empty address.
      }

   }
```

I did create function repopulating the `Address` and `Country` records for me, similar to this:

```golang
func PopulateUser(user) User {

   addr = FindAddresByID(user.ID)
   cntr = FindCountryByCode(addr.Code)

   addr.Country = cntr
   user.Address = addr

   return user

}
```

but my questions:

1. is there a function in `Gorm` which can do that for me without me creating the function?
2. can Associations help in this case?
3. if I want the address to be deleted when the user deleted, how I can do this in `Gorm`?

I tried to find answers on my own, but the documentation is a bit messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html#Override-References) shows the foreign key tags to go at the struct reference.
i.e in your case those should be at Address and Country instead of AddressID and CountryCode. Something like:

```golang
type User struct {
      Address         Address `gorm:"foreignKey:AddressID;references:ID"`
      AddressID       int  `gorm:"column:address_id"`
   }

type Address struct {
      CountryCode int `gorm:"column:country_code"`
      Country     Country gorm:"foreignKey:CountryCode; references:Code"`
   }
```

Please try with those.

For

1. Please see eager loading [here](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html)

```golang
db.Preload("User").Preload("Address").Find(&users)
```

3. You can use [cascade](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#FOREIGN-KEY-Constraints) tag on the column.

```golang
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name      string
  CompanyID int
  Company   Company `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
}
```